# How to find the code causes a :hover action on DOM element?

Tags: javascript, css, debugging, hover, onmouseover

I have  element in code. When I mouse over it there shows button on image. I'm trying to find out what code is responsible for that mouse over action.

I tried to make Breaks in Chrome's Dev Tools - no result. I was looking for hover in CSS, no such attributes. I have no ideas what to do next, how to debug that code.

Talking in details, I'm talking about element "add to cart" showing when you hover image on this shop template: https://demo.themeisle.com/shop-isle/product-category/clothing/dresses/

Thanks for any suggestions,
Lukasz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the **:hov** option in the Chrome debugging tools under **Elements > Styles**. You can then trigger various element states (e.g: hover).

[image]

As explained in the following image, the `.product:hover .product-button-wrap` style controls how the add button is displayed when the product is hovered over. `.product:hover` sets the style for all elements with the CSS class `product` when they are hovered over. `.product:hover .product-button-wrap` sets the style of any elements with the class `product-button-wrap` when they belong to an element with class `product` that is hovered over.

[image]

Comment: Nice... How did you know that? I also tried filter :hover but I couldn't find out that some child element gets :hover. Did you check every child element? If I force :hover for <div class="product-button-wrap"> there is no effect, button is still hidden.

Comment: The reason triggering hover on the .product-button-wrap doesn't display is because there isn't a specific CSS rule defined for when the .product-button-wrap element is hovered over. And given the .product-button-wrap element isn't initially visible (because it's opacity is 0) there's no way a user can see it to hover over it.

The .product:hover .product-button-wrap selector selects any .product-button-wrap elements that are inside .product elements that are hovered over.

Comment: I understand that but still I don't see the way to fast finding out such things. You did that quick so I think you have some good method :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.product:hover .product-button-wrap, .shop-item:hover .product-button-wrap {
    bottom: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s;
    transition: all .4s;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(50%);
    transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

Hover on closest `.product` triggers animation

Answer (score 0):

Select that div element that has mouseover on "elements" tab.
Then select "Event Listeners" below. Now expand "mouseover". You will see lazyload.1.0.5.min.js:1 link. Click that link. That will get you on "Sources" tab.
Now in the lower left corner of minified source there is "{}" button it says "pretty print" when you mouseover, click it.
Now on elements=>event listeners you'll have lazyload.1.0.5.min.js:79 link.
From there you can see source string numbers. Left clicking those numbers you can set breakpoints :)

```
return function(force) {
    if (running) {
        return
    }
    var delay = lazyRocketsConfig.throttle - (Date.now() - lastTime);
    running = true;
    if (delay < 4) {
        delay = 4
    }
    if (force === true) {
        getAF()
    } else {
        setTimeout(getAF, delay)
    }
}
```